# Is there a way to get a list of innerclasses in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, inner-classes

As per the title. I'd like a list of all the inner classes of a given class, it can be a list of names or a list of types - I am not fussed. Is this possible? I thought there might be a way using reflection but haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Also, use of the phrase "inner classes" suggests you may have Java experience. It is worth pointing out that in C# these are called "nested classes", and they are closer to Java's "static nested classes" than Java's "inner classes".

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You want [Type.GetNestedTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493t6h7t.aspx).  This will give you the list of types, which you can then query for their names.

Comment: As in `type.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredNestedTypes`.

Answer (score 12):

Doesn't [`Type.GetNestedTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getnestedtypes.aspx) do what you want?

Note that if you want to get "double-nested" types, you'll need to recurse - as Foo.Bar.Baz is a nested type in Foo.Bar, not in Foo.

For "modern" environments (.NET 4.5, PCLs, UWA etc) you need [`TypeInfo.DeclaredNestedTypes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.declarednestedtypes) instead, e.g. `type.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredNestedTypes`, using the [`GetTypeInfo()` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It seems that in Windows 8.1 there's no "GetNestedTypes" method. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @superpuccio: As with so many things in modern reflection, you want `TypeInfo` - in this case, `TypeInfo.DeclaredNestedTypes`.

Comment: As in `typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredNestedTypes`.

Comment: @ErikE: Duly clarified.

Answer (score 7):

[Type.GetNestedTypes(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/266a0de6.aspx)) will return the public nested types of the specified Type.

If you also want the private and internal nested types, you must call the [Type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags bindingFlags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493t6h7t.aspx) method like this:

```
Type[] nestedTypes = typeof(MyType).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Static |
                                                   BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                   BindingFlags.Public |
                                                   BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Type[] nested = typeof(SomeClass).GetNestedTypes();
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. Use [`Type.GetNestedTypes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getnestedtypes%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).