# how to get list of inner class inside a class and create instance

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know how I can get a list of instances of all the inner classes I have in the class of FormStore. I am using .NET 4.5 and C#.

```
namespace test
{
    public class FormStore
    {


        public partial class child1 : Form
        {

        }

        public partial class child2 : Form
        {

        }

        public partial class child3 : Form
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve here? You want to know what are all the classes defined under a specific class at runtime? Can you share some relevant details? You can start with exploring reflection.

Comment: Is this what you're asking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5566476/4180382

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a list of innerclasses in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566428/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-innerclasses-in-c)

Comment: @OfirWinegarten: it could be but my problem was when it is extended from Form class how it should be managed.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: I was looking for a way create an instance of my classes dynamically which Esperento57 answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reflection, like this (more détails [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493t6h7t.aspx)):

```
 var ListNestedTypes = typeof(test.FormStore).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredNestedTypes;

 foreach (var item in ListNestedTypes)
 {
      string Nameclass = item.Name;
 }
```

Comment: Then assume I want to add those classes to a list<Form>, how should I do it?

Comment: This class are not instancied, it's only definition. List<Form> is a list of instance of class (list of objects), its differents

Comment: So from the definition, how we can create an instance/object of them?

Comment: look this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958825/c-sharp-creating-instance-of-class-and-set-properties-by-name-in-string

Comment: tq so much. I got my answer.